# Is it possible to run WSO2 ESB in Openshift?

Tags: wso2

We are trying to create a WSO2 ESB cartridge to run on Openshift but haven't had much success yet. Is it even possible to run WSO2 ESB on Openshift or do we have to rely on Fuse ESB?  Happy to run WSO2 either through cartridge option or just an EAR file if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install WSO2 ESB in an Openshift DIY cartridge. But I'm getting an port binding issue. The nasty thing is the message does not say which port it is unable to be bind into.

Please let me know if you passed this stage while trying to deploy WSO2 ESB in Openshift.

> [esb3-yasas.rhcloud.com bin]> sh wso2server.sh
>
> Starting WSO2 Carbon (in unsupported JDK)  [ERROR] CARBON is
>   supported only on JDK 1.6 and 1.7 JAVA_HOME environment variable is
>   set to
>   /var/lib/openshift/57dca6070c1e66b48000003c/app-root/data/java/jdk1.8.0_45/
>   CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to
>   /var/lib/openshift/57dca6070c1e66b48000003c/app-root/data/esb Java
>   HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option
>   MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0 Error: Exception thrown
>   by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use:
>   0; nested exception is:
>           java.net.BindException: Permission denied

[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jmn0c.png)

Thanks !